# How to find last matching element in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I wanted to do find by `class_name` and return last element among all elements.

In jquery, we can write something like below but that don't seems to work in capybara

```
find(".delete:last")
```

If you are using `webkit` driver you can write something like -

```
find(".delete:last-child")
```

In capybara, you can get last element using below -

```
all(:css, ".delete").last
```

Is there any alternative to above?

Comment: Which driver do you use? `'.delete:last-child'` should work with selenium

Comment: Actually i wanted to find out other alternatives in capybara (not driver specific)

Comment: That's not driver-specific solution. It should work in all drivers that support properly CSS selectors.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov may be i could have been doing something wrong that time then.. thanks !

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I had the same problem and ended up using this method in Capybara 2.4

```
all('.delete').last
```

Comment: Thanks man. Didn't realize there was an `all`.

In case anyone is wondering why this is an issue, `find` returns the matched node (good) or throws an exception if there is more than one match (bad). So pseudo selectors don't work.

Comment: FYI for future readers:  Keep in mind that `all` unlike `find` will not wait for any elements; it has no way to predict how many there should be.  It's a good idea to make sure you've verified that any asynchronous activity on the page is complete before using this.

Comment: This works well with `within`, too, so you can do `within all('li').last { fill_in "Name", with: "Value" }`

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Sharagoz answer and @tgf's comment about all (unlike find) not waiting for async to finish, this combination seems to work for me:

```
wait_for_ajax
all('.selector').last
```

With this added to rspec/capybara:

```
module RspecFeatureHelpers
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
      loop do
        active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
        break if active == 0
      end
    end
  end
end
```